# How to compute quantity times price textbox to listbox

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the following code. I have a quantity textbox and price textbox. I need to multiple the price by the quatity to display total in a listbox of a particular item. the listbox gets totaled at the end. This worked as a static array just fine but I had to allow for user input of different price and quantity. I provided code in the middle that I thought might work but doesn't. What am I ding wrong?  ''''''''''''PriceTextBox.Text = PriceTextBox * QuantityTextBox.Text'''''''''''''

```
 Public Class form1

'Module level declarations
Structure Product
    Dim ProductIDString As String
    Dim DescriptionString As String
    Dim QuantityInteger As Integer
    Dim PriceDecimal As Decimal
    Dim W As IO.StreamWriter
End Structure

Private NumberProductsInteger As Integer = 38
Private InventoryProduct(NumberProductsInteger) As Product
Private TotalDueDecimal As Decimal 'total due for a customer

'Array to store the total sales for each product
Private ProductSalesTotalDecimal(NumberProductsInteger) As Decimal




Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PurchaseBtn.Click
    'Test to determine if a product was found.
    If DescriptionTextBox.Text = String.Empty Then

        'Cannot purchase, product was not found
        MessageBox.Show("You must select a valid product before purchasing.", "Cannot Purchase", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        ProductIDTextBox.Focus()
        ProductIDTextBox.SelectAll()
    Else
        'Can purchase the product
        'Build a string to display in the listbox control
        Dim ProductString As String = ProductIDTextBox.Text & "  " & DescriptionTextBox.Text & "    " & QuantityTextBox.Text & "                " & PriceTextBox.Text
        PurchaseListBox.Items.Add(ProductString)

        'Accumulate the total value of this customer order
        'and display it to the output textbox


        ''''''''''''PriceTextBox.Text = PriceTextBox * QuantityTextBox.Text'''''''''''''



        TotalDueDecimal += Decimal.Parse(PriceTextBox.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)
        TotalDueTextBox.Text = TotalDueDecimal.ToString("C2")

        'Accumulate total sales by product to an array
        Dim IndexInteger As Integer = ProductIDComboBox.SelectedIndex
        ProductSalesTotalDecimal(IndexInteger) += Decimal.Parse(PriceTextBox.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)

        'Here you can clear the form of product info if you think
        'that is a good way to do the processing
        ProductIDComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1
        ProductIDTextBox.Clear()
        DescriptionTextBox.Clear()
        PriceTextBox.Clear()
        QuantityTextBox.Clear()
        ProductIDTextBox.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see the total due adds up the prices but doesn't add in the quantity factor

[image]

Public Class form1
    Structure Product

```
    'Module level declarations
    Dim ProductIDString As String
    Dim DescriptionString As String
    Dim QuantityInteger As Integer
    Dim PriceDecimal As Double
    Dim Cost As Double
    Dim W As IO.StreamWriter


    Public Sub New(PID As String, Desc As String, Qty As Integer, Price As Double)
        ProductIDString = PID
        DescriptionString = Desc
        QuantityInteger = Qty
        PriceDecimal = Price
        Cost = Qty * Price
    End Sub





    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return ProductIDString & " " & DescriptionString & " " & QuantityInteger.ToString & " " & PriceDecimal.ToString("C2") & " " & Cost.ToString("C2")
    End Function
End Structure


Dim Products As New List(Of Product)

'Products..AddRange(
' New Product("test1", "Test1a", 10, 1.5),
'  NewProduct("test2", "test2a", 20, 2.25)




' PurchaseListBox.DataSource = Products
' TotalDueTextBox.Text = Products.Sum(Function(x) x.Cost).ToString("C2")

Public Sub UpdateLB()
    PurchaseListBox.DataSource = Nothing
    PurchaseListBox.DataSource = Products
    TotalDueTextBox.Text = Products.Sum(Function(x) x.Cost).ToString("C2")
End Sub

Private NumberProductsInteger As Integer = 38
Private InventoryProduct(NumberProductsInteger) As Product
Private TotalDueDecimal As Decimal 'total due for a customer
Private Property W As IO.StreamWriter
Private ProductSalesTotalDecimal(NumberProductsInteger) As Decimal  'Array to store the total sales for each product

Private Sub BookStore1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TimeDateLBL.Text = CStr(Date.Now)

    'Initialize values - InventoryProduct array
    InventoryProduct(0).ProductIDString = "102-1091" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(0).DescriptionString = "2x4-92 & Chr(96)  5/8  SPF  STUD" & vbTab & vbTab
    'InventoryProduct(0).QuantityInteger = 
    ' InventoryProduct(0).PriceDecimal = 65.55D

    InventoryProduct(1).ProductIDString = "102-1127" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(1).DescriptionString = "2x4-12'  #2 &BTR  SPF  CONSTR  LUMB" & Space(33)
    'InventoryProduct(1).QuantityInteger = 15
    'InventoryProduct(1).PriceDecimal = 18.99D

    InventoryProduct(2).ProductIDString = "102-1130" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(2).DescriptionString = "2x4-14'  #2&BTR  SPF  CONSTR LUMB" & Space(35)
    ' InventoryProduct(2).QuantityInteger = 25
    ' InventoryProduct(2).PriceDecimal = 25.99D

    InventoryProduct(3).ProductIDString = "102-1143" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(3).DescriptionString = "2x4-16'  5/8  #2&BTR  SPF  CONSTR LUMB" & Space(27)
    ' InventoryProduct(3).QuantityInteger = 8
    'InventoryProduct(3).PriceDecimal = 5.49D

    InventoryProduct(4).ProductIDString = "102-1305" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(4).DescriptionString = "2x4-104  5/8  SPF  STUD" & Space(64)
    ' InventoryProduct(4).QuantityInteger = 15
    ' InventoryProduct(4).PriceDecimal = 35.5D

    InventoryProduct(5).ProductIDString = "102-1758" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(5).DescriptionString = "2x6-8'  STD/#2&BTR  SPF  CONSTR LUMB" & Space(33)
    ' InventoryProduct(5).QuantityInteger = 25
    ' InventoryProduct(5).PriceDecimal = 22.99D

    InventoryProduct(6).ProductIDString = "102-1774" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(6).DescriptionString = "2x6-12' #2&BTR  SPF  CONSTR LUMB" & Space(33)
    ' InventoryProduct(6).QuantityInteger = 50
    ' InventoryProduct(6).PriceDecimal = 85D

    InventoryProduct(7).ProductIDString = "102-1923" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(7).DescriptionString = "2x8-16' #2&BTR  SPF  CONSTR LUMB"
    ' InventoryProduct(7).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(7).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(8).ProductIDString = "102-2184" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(8).DescriptionString = "2x12-16'  #2&BTR  SPF  CONSTR LUMB  "
    ' InventoryProduct(8).QuantityInteger = 75
    'InventoryProduct(8).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(9).ProductIDString = "106-1501" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(9).DescriptionString = "1-3/4x11-7/8  10'  LVL"
    'InventoryProduct(9).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(9).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(10).ProductIDString = "106-2089" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(10).DescriptionString = "1-3/4x11-7/8  10'  LVL"
    ' InventoryProduct(10).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(10).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(11).ProductIDString = "106-2115" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(11).DescriptionString = "1-3/4x14  14'  LVL"
    ' InventoryProduct(11).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(11).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(12).ProductIDString = "106-2144" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(12).DescriptionString = "1-3/4x14  18'  LVL"
    ' InventoryProduct(12).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(12).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(13).ProductIDString = "106-2209" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(13).DescriptionString = "1-3/4x14  26'  20'  LVL"
    ' InventoryProduct(13).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(13).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(14).ProductIDString = "106-6742" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(14).DescriptionString = "2-1/2X14-18' I Joist  NI-60/PRi-60"
    ' InventoryProduct(14).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(14).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(15).ProductIDString = "106-6768" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(15).DescriptionString = "2-1/2X14-18' I Joist  NI-60/PRi-60"
    ' InventoryProduct(15).QuantityInteger = 75
    'InventoryProduct(15).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(16).ProductIDString = "106-6807" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(16).DescriptionString = "2-1/2X14-24' I Joist  NI-60/PRi-60"
    ' InventoryProduct(16).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(16).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(17).ProductIDString = "106-8106" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(17).DescriptionString = "2-1/2X14-12' I Joist  RIM BOARD"
    ' InventoryProduct(17).QuantityInteger = 75
    'InventoryProduct(17).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(18).ProductIDString = "111-0834" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(18).DescriptionString = "2x4-12'  AC2 TREATED  AG LIFETIME WTY"
    ' InventoryProduct(18).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(18).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(19).ProductIDString = "111-0847" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(19).DescriptionString = "2x4-14'  AC2 TREATED  AG LIFETIME WTY"""
    ' InventoryProduct(19).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(19).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(20).ProductIDString = "124-2728" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(20).DescriptionString = "7/16  (14/32)-4 XB  OSB 3-WHITE STRIPES"
    'InventoryProduct(20).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(20).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(21).ProductIDString = "124-2809" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(21).DescriptionString = "1/2  (16/32)-4 XB  OSB 2-WHITE BLAK  STRIPES" & Space(17)

    ' InventoryProduct(21).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(21).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(22).ProductIDString = "124-2867" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(22).DescriptionString = "3/4  (23/32)-4 XB  OSB T&G 5-WHITE STRIPES"
    ' InventoryProduct(22).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(22).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(23).ProductIDString = "131-1248" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(23).DescriptionString = "1/2x4'-12'  GYPsum  78LBL"
    ' InventoryProduct(23).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(23).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(24).ProductIDString = "131-1256" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(24).DescriptionString = "1/2x4'-8'  MOLD/MR  78LBL"
    ' InventoryProduct(24).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(24).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(25).ProductIDString = "131-1259" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(25).DescriptionString = "5/8x4'-8'  MOLD/MR TYPR X   105LBL"
    ' InventoryProduct(25).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(25).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(26).ProductIDString = "131-1303" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(26).DescriptionString = "5/8X4-12'  GYPS PC TYPE  X 105LBL"
    '  InventoryProduct(26).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(26).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(27).ProductIDString = "131-2454" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(27).DescriptionString = "8' METAL 1-1/4 CORNERBEAD"
    '  InventoryProduct(27).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(27).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(28).ProductIDString = "131-2726" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(28).DescriptionString = "ALL PURPOSE PALE-BLACK 7GAL"
    ' InventoryProduct(28).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(28).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(29).ProductIDString = "131-2849" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(29).DescriptionString = "EZ SAND  90  18#"
    ' InventoryProduct(29).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(29).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(30).ProductIDString = "131-2881" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(30).DescriptionString = "SPRAY-TEXTURE MEDIUM  40#"
    ' InventoryProduct(30).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(30).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(31).ProductIDString = "131-3097" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(31).DescriptionString = "PROROC JOINT TAPE  250'"
    ' InventoryProduct(31).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(31).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(32).ProductIDString = "165-0372" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(32).DescriptionString = "M/H208  ANJ COLUMN 3INCH DIAM -8'4"
    ' InventoryProduct(32).QuantityInteger = 75
    '  InventoryProduct(32).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(33).ProductIDString = "227-1442" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(33).DescriptionString = "NAIL 1-1/2 JOIST HANGER   5LB GALV"
    ' InventoryProduct(33).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(33).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(34).ProductIDString = "228-3142" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(34).DescriptionString = "JOIST HNGR  TM 2.5X14  THO54140"
    ' InventoryProduct(34).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(34).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(35).ProductIDString = "229-1202" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(35).DescriptionString = "NAIL 8D  V.C.  SINKERS   50LBL BOX"
    ' InventoryProduct(35).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(35).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(36).ProductIDString = "229-1244" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(36).DescriptionString = "NAIL 16D  V.C.  SINKERS   50LBL BOX"""
    ' InventoryProduct(36).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(36).PriceDecimal = 79.4D

    InventoryProduct(37).ProductIDString = "229-1303" & vbTab
    InventoryProduct(37).DescriptionString = "NAIL 16D  GALVANZED BOX  50LBL BOX"""
    ' InventoryProduct(37).QuantityInteger = 75
    ' InventoryProduct(37).PriceDecimal = 79.4D
End Sub

Private Sub SearchButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click

    'Search the ProductIDString property of the inventoryProduct
    'array to see if the value of ProductIDTextBox matches an ID 
    'in the array

    'Start variables to control the search
    Dim FoundBoolean As Boolean = False  'Control how long to search
    Dim RowInteger As Integer = 0        'Current row in the search

    'Loop to do the search
    Do Until FoundBoolean = True Or RowInteger > NumberProductsInteger

        'Compare textBox to array
        If ProductIDTextBox.Text = InventoryProduct(RowInteger).ProductIDString Then

            'found a match - display other data to the readonly textboxes
            ProductIDComboBox.SelectedItem = ProductIDTextBox.Text
            DescriptionTextBox.Text = InventoryProduct(RowInteger).DescriptionString
            QuantityTextBox.Text = InventoryProduct(RowInteger).QuantityInteger.ToString
            PriceTextBox.Text = InventoryProduct(RowInteger).PriceDecimal.ToString("C2")

            'change variable to indicate we have a match
            FoundBoolean = True
        Else
            'no match yet
            RowInteger += 1
        End If
    Loop

    'After the search determine if the ProductID was found

    If FoundBoolean = False Then  'no match was found
        'Clear the textbox controls that display product information
        'except for the ProductID textbox
        DescriptionTextBox.Clear()
        QuantityTextBox.Clear()
        PriceTextBox.Clear()
        ProductIDComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1

        'Display message that the ProductID is not valid
        MessageBox.Show("Reenter a valid SKU Product ID.", "Invalid Identifier", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        ProductIDTextBox.Focus()
        ProductIDTextBox.SelectAll()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PurchaseToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PurchaseToolStripMenuItem.Click

    'Test to determine if a product was found.
    If DescriptionTextBox.Text = String.Empty Then

        'Cannot purchase, product was not found
        MessageBox.Show("You must select a valid product before purchasing.", "Cannot Purchase", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        ProductIDTextBox.Focus()
        ProductIDTextBox.SelectAll()
    Else
        'Can purchase the product
        'Build a string to display in the listbox control
        Dim ProductString As String = ProductIDTextBox.Text & " - " & DescriptionTextBox.Text & " - " & PriceTextBox.Text
        PurchaseListBox.Items.Add(ProductString)

        'Accumulate the total value of this customer order
        'and display it to the output textbox
        TotalDueDecimal += Decimal.Parse(PriceTextBox.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)
        TotalDueTextBox.Text = TotalDueDecimal.ToString("C2")

        'Accumulate total sales by product to an array
        Dim IndexInteger As Integer = ProductIDComboBox.SelectedIndex
        ProductSalesTotalDecimal(IndexInteger) += Decimal.Parse(PriceTextBox.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)

        'Here you can clear the form of product info if you think
        'that is a good way to do the processing
        ProductIDComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1
        ProductIDTextBox.Clear()
        DescriptionTextBox.Clear()
        PriceTextBox.Clear()
        QuantityTextBox.Clear()
        ProductIDTextBox.Focus()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ResetToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ResetToolStripMenuItem.Click
    'Clear all text box and combobox controls
    ProductIDComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1
    ProductIDTextBox.Clear()
    DescriptionTextBox.Clear()
    PriceTextBox.Clear()
    QuantityTextBox.Clear()
    ' TotalDueTextBox.Clear()

    'Clear the list box control
    PurchaseListBox.Items.Clear()

    'Reset the total due module-level variable to zero
    TotalDueDecimal = 0

    'Set the focus to the product ID text box
    ProductIDTextBox.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub SearchToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchToolStripMenuItem.Click
    'Call the Click event for theSearch button control
    SearchButton.PerformClick()
End Sub

Private Sub AboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AboutToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim MessageString As String = "Version 1 John Burtons Building Cost Estimater" & ControlChars.NewLine & "Today's date/time: " & Date.Now
    Dim TitleString As String = "About Version 1"

    MessageBox.Show(MessageString, TitleString, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End Sub

Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click

    'Close the form
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ProductIDComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ProductIDComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged

    'Test to determine if a product has been selected
    If ProductIDComboBox.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then

        'Store the selectedIndex to variable
        Dim RowInteger As Integer = ProductIDComboBox.SelectedIndex

        'Based on RowInteger, display values to TextBox controls
        'from the array named inventoryProduct
        ProductIDTextBox.Text = InventoryProduct(RowInteger).ProductIDString
        DescriptionTextBox.Text = InventoryProduct(RowInteger).DescriptionString
        QuantityTextBox.Text = InventoryProduct(RowInteger).QuantityInteger.ToString("N0")
        PriceTextBox.Text = InventoryProduct(RowInteger).PriceDecimal.ToString("C2")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TotalSalesByProductToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TotalSalesByProductToolStripMenuItem.Click
    'Display output to immediate window
    Dim RowInteger As Integer
    Dim SalesString As String = "ProductID" & vbTab & "Dollar Sales" & vbCrLf
    For Each ProductItem As Product In InventoryProduct
        'Build string to display
        SalesString &= ProductItem.ProductIDString & vbTab & vbTab & ProductSalesTotalDecimal(RowInteger).ToString("C2") & vbCrLf

        'Increment RowInteger
        RowInteger += 1
    Next
    'Display string to a MessageBox
    'Debug.WriteLine(SalesString)
    MessageBox.Show(SalesString, "Sales for all Products", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End Sub



Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PurchaseBtn.Click
    'Test to determine if a product was found.
    If DescriptionTextBox.Text = String.Empty Then

        'Cannot purchase, product was not found
        MessageBox.Show("You must select a valid product before purchasing.", "Cannot Purchase", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        ProductIDTextBox.Focus()
        ProductIDTextBox.SelectAll()
    Else
        'Can purchase the product
        'Build a string to display in the listbox control
        Dim ProductString As String = ProductIDTextBox.Text & "  " & DescriptionTextBox.Text & "    " & QuantityTextBox.Text & "     " & PriceTextBox.Text
        PurchaseListBox.Items.Add(ProductString)


        ' Dim Total As Double
        '  For i = 0 To PurchaseListBox.Items.Count
        'Total += Convert.ToDouble(PriceTextBox.Items.Item(i)) * Convert.ToDouble(QuantityTextBox.Items.Item(i))
        ' Next i
        ' Debug.WriteLine(Total)


        'Accumulate the total value of this customer order
        'and display it to the output textbox

        TotalDueDecimal += Decimal.Parse(PriceTextBox.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)
        TotalDueTextBox.Text = Products.Sum(Function(x) x.Cost).ToString("C2")
        ' TotalDueTextBox.Text = TotalDueDecimal.ToString("C2")

        'Accumulate total sales by product to an array
        Dim IndexInteger As Integer = ProductIDComboBox.SelectedIndex
        ProductSalesTotalDecimal(IndexInteger) += Decimal.Parse(PriceTextBox.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)

        'Here you can clear the form of product info if you think
        'that is a good way to do the processing
        ProductIDComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1
        ProductIDTextBox.Clear()
        DescriptionTextBox.Clear()
        PriceTextBox.Clear()
        QuantityTextBox.Clear()
        ProductIDTextBox.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub SaveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SaveAsToolStripMenuItem.Click

    sFile.InitialDirectory = ("C:\")
    sFile.FileName = ("Save As...")
    sFile.Filter = ("Only Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt")
    sFile.ShowDialog()

    Dim W As New IO.StreamWriter(sFile.FileName, True)  ' notes from class need messgbox
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To PurchaseListBox.Items.Count - 1
        W.WriteLine(PurchaseListBox.Items.Item(i))

        Dim L As New IO.StreamWriter(sFile.FileName, True)
        L.WriteLine(TotalDueTextBox)


        ' Next
        ' Dim L As New IO.StreamWriter(sFile.FileName)
        ' For i = 0 To TotalDueTextBox.Items.Count - 1
        'W.WriteLine(TotalDueTextBox.Items.Item(i))

    Next
    W.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub PriceTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PriceTextBox.TextChanged



End Sub

' Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
'Dim num1, num2, product As Decimal

'  num1 = PriceTextBox.Text
'  num2 = QuantityTextBox.Text
' product = num1 * num2
' TextBox3.Text = product
' PriceTextBox.Text = TextBox3.Text


'  End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I can see PRICE added to something, and TotalDue incremented by the price, but no mutliplication, cant tell which is the quanity

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `.Value` properties, not the `.Text` properties of your controls.

Comment: is there a way to add pic of GUI here I think it would clear everything up

Answer (score 0):

```
If Integer.TryParse(txtQuan.Text,ItemQuan) = False then
       ' fail msg
End If

PriceDec = ' parse like above...current code parses Price twice and
    ' ADDS to sales total the second time

Dim TotalDue as Decimal = ItemQuan * PriceDec 
TotalDueTextBox.Text = TotalDue.ToString("C2")
```

Comment: Don't think this is going to work. when user enters price into PriceTextox, clicks button. the prce get put into an array and listed in the listbox. at the end of the listbox is a totalDue textbox that adds the entire list entered into the listbox. this works very well I do not need to mess with this. What ever is entered in the PriceTextbox gets added and summed well. However bfore this step I need to multiple that pricetextbox to the quantityTextbox. Keep in mind hat both the priceTextBox and QuaantityTextBox are user defined meaning the input their vaue.

Comment: The OP and code comment `PriceTextBox.Text = PriceTextBox * QuantityTextBox.Text` doesnt mention an array, though I could see one being used just not waht it was used for or why.

Comment: couldn't fgure out how to use it. only problem I see with that is it will list the total for each item and add to grand total. What I think I need is something that works under the covers that displays the quantity for an item, the cost of one item, cost * quantity for that item. then at the bottom a grand total for total purchase price.

Answer (score 0):

> I had to allow for user input of different price and quantity

Sometimes a little re-design can give you your answer and make things easier for you at the same time.

First off a list is better suited to what you want.

A new constructor and a tostring override will help in this:

```
Structure Product
    Dim ProductIDString As String
    Dim DescriptionString As String
    Dim QuantityInteger As Integer
    Dim PriceDecimal As Double
    Dim Cost As Double
    Dim W As IO.StreamWriter
    Public Sub New(PID As String, Desc As String, Qty As Integer, Price As Double)
        ProductIDString = PID
        DescriptionString = Desc
        QuantityInteger = Qty
        PriceDecimal = Price
        Cost = Qty * Price
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return ProductIDString & " " & DescriptionString & " " & QuantityInteger.ToString & " " & PriceDecimal.ToString("C2") & " " & Cost.ToString("C2")
    End Function
End Structure

Dim Products As New List(Of Product)
```

Adding items to the list is now very simple using the new constructor:

```
    Products.AddRange(
        {
            New Product("test1", "Test1a", 10, 1.5),
            New Product("test2", "test2a", 20, 2.25)
        })
```

The ToString() method can be used to populate the listbox using the DataSource property:

```
    ListBox1.DataSource = Products
```

Now anytime you want to update the total you have access to the Sum method which can be used to total the Cost properties of the items in the list:

```
    Label1.Text = Products.Sum(Function(x) x.Cost).ToString("C2")
```

Anytime you want to add a new product to the list a simple sub routine will work to update the listbox and the total:

```
Public Sub UpdateLB()
    ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
    ListBox1.DataSource = Products
    Label1.Text = Products.Sum(Function(x) x.Cost).ToString("C2")
End Sub
```

When adding a new product check for empty strings, validate and parse the ones that need it, then add the new product to the list and call UpdatLB.

A side not, you might want to consider using Double instead of Decimal as Decimal sometimes can have rounding errors.

Not sure why you have the streamwriter in the structure, but if you need to write the products to a file, simply iterating through the list and calling the ToString method of each item, you can write that string to the file.

Comment: I get errors here,     Products.AddRange(
        {
            New Product("test1", "Test1a", 10, 1.5),
            New Product("test2", "test2a", 20, 2.25)
        })

    PurchaseListBox.DataSource = Products
    TotalDueTextBox.Text = Products.Sum(Function(x) x.Cost).ToString("C2")

Comment: Did you add the 'Cost' property to the Product Structure?

Comment: Do you have System.LINQ imported? - `Imports System.Linq` Plus it appears you forgot the {}'s in your AddRange statement.

Comment: Also the space between New and Products is important.

Comment: still getting syntax errors. What does the {} do in VB I have never used them. I will do some research on Import Systems.Linq to find out what I do with it.   Dim Products As New List(Of Product)

    Product.AddRange(
     {New Products("test1", "Test1a", 10, 1.5),
     New Products("test2", "test2a", 20, 2.25)})

Comment: my understanding is that Imports System.Linq  is a default program for VB 2010

Comment: the braces({}) denote a collection.  In this case a collection of type `Product`.  The syntax error is because you're using `Products` which is a list, instead of `Product` which is the type of object in the `Products` list.  Sorry my bad, just noticed my previous comment said Products by mistake.  You may right about LINQ.  I only threw that out there in case it was needed for the Sum Method.